# Find out if a user is friends with exactly one other user using Graph API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, koala

I'm trying to find out if User A is friends with User B but I don't want User A's entire list of friends. Is there a way, using Koala / the Graph API to simply find out if User A is friends with User B just using User B's Facebook ID?

Comment: Thanks for the answers all. I ended up going with a combination of the two:

Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new(oauth_access_token).get_connections(user1_id, "friends/#{user2_id}").empty?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends/{friend's user id}

If they are friends it will return the ID and Name, if not an empty array.

Comment: Thanks Andy! I figured this out last night and didn't update the question. I'm wasn't able to find a method for this in Koala (since there's no documentation on the args param) but it might work with that.

Comment: Seriously, It does not work. It returns always empty array in `data` even if a user is friend. And it returns total count of my friends.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily with FQL.

```
query = "SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me() and uid2=FRIEDS ID HERE"

@rest = Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_access_token)
# in 1.1 or earlier, use RestAPI instead of API

@rest.fql_query(query) # convenience method
```

You can test it here if you append an access token.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me() and uid2=123456
```

You can also check multiples at one with:

```
SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me() and uid2 in (123,1234)
```

Comment: Thanks Gazler. I ended up using the following call:

Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new(oauth_access_token).get_connections(user1_id, "friends/#{user2_id}").empty?